# How do you configure the default dependencies in a new Gradle project in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, dependencies

After I added some dependencies to build.gradle

```
compile(
   "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.1.6.RELEASE",
   "org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.0.RELEASE",
   "org.springframework:spring-test:4.1.0.RELEASE",
   "javax.inject:javax.inject:1",
   "org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5",
   "org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.2.1",
   "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2",
   "com.google.guava:guava:18.0"
)
```

and refreshing the IntelliJ Gradle plugin, many more dependencies appear in the Gradle libs list inside "External Libs"

I suspect this is nothing to do with the plugin, but rather gradle augmenting my dependencies from somewhere else but I can't work out from where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like in Maven, the dependencies you declared can have further dependencies that are declared by the package supplier (a.k.a transitive dependency management) - those will be added automatically, just like you observed.
More info [here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html).